# Type of primitive functions in lazy evaluation

Tags: c, haskell, functional-programming, lazy-evaluation

I want to know what the exact type of primitive functions in lazy functional programming languages like Haskell is.

Let's say thunks are evaluated to objects of weak head normal form. Then, what should be the type of primitive functions in strict languages like C?

My guesses are:

```
primitive1 : (thunk, thunk, ...) -> thunk
primitive2 : (thunk, thunk, ...) -> object
```

I think primitive functions should be passed thunks as arguments because they may not need some of them. But, I don't know if they should return a thunk or evaluated object while the later one must be wrapped with some function like the below to make it lazy.

```
lazy : ((thunk, thunk, ...) -> object) -> ((thunk, thunk, ...) -> thunk)
```

Comment: Well, there is no unique answer to this question since it depends on the implementation.  In ghc the primitive operations have primitive types, i.e., the same types as in C.  You have separate operation for wrapping and unwrapping the primitive types in thunks.

Comment: @augustss How about if and case expressions? Their primitives must be passed thunks directly, I guess. Or, are they curried?

Comment: An if expression is translated into a case expression.  And there is no primitive for case, it's translated into (abstract) machine code that depends on the type.  Simplified, first the scrutinee is evaluated to WHNF, then you extract its constructor number and use that as an offset in a jump table. The code you jump to will unpack the fields of the constructor and proceed with evaluation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GHC, a Haskell primitive function (sometimes called a PrimOp) is
called with a mixture of pointers (to "heap objects") and unboxed
types (including C-style ints, doubles, etc).  The Haskell type system
ensures that PrimOps always get the number, order, and types of the
pointers and unboxed values that they are expecting.  It's important
to note, though, that where a primitive is expecting a pointer to a specific type of heap object, say a `String`,
it is expecting a pointer to a heap object that may *either* be a list
constructor (since a Haskell `String` is a list of characters) **or** a thunk
that can be evaluated to a list constructor.

So, the "strict" type of a Haskell PrimOp doesn't differentiate
between thunks and non-thunks.  If there was a primitive function to
get a list's length, for example (there isn't), it would likely have type, using your notation, of:

```
primitiveLength : (list_object) -> unboxed_int
```

where the `list_object` would be a pointer to **either** a list
constructor **or** a thunk that can yield a list constructor.

This is really the only sensible approach.  A PrimOp can't control whether its argument is still a thunk or has been partially (or fully!) evaluated by some previous computation, so it has to be ready to accept either.

Similarly, if a Haskell PrimOp *returns* a heap object, that object could technically either be a thunk or non-thunk, and the choice would have no effect on the primitive's "strict" type signature.

In practice, it's not very useful for a PrimOp to return a thunk.  In a lazy language, the fact that the primitive is being called implies that its return value is needed.  If it returns a thunk, that thunk will need to be evaluated right away, so why return a thunk?

(Edited to add:)  By the way, there's nothing really specific to PrimOps above: user-defined Haskell functions are also called with a mixture of pointers and unboxed types, too (and they never return thunks).

Comment: Are both creation and evaluation of thunks allowed in primitive functions?

Comment: Primitives *can* evaluate thunks, but few do.  For example, `newArray#` can take a thunk (as the initial value for the array elements), but it doesn't evaluate it -- it just populates the array with pointers to the thunk.  I guess `raise#` is an example of a primitive that accepts (and evaluates) a thunk.  Since evaluating a thunk can create new thunks, this means `raise#` is capable of *implicitly* creating thunks, too.  I don't know of a primitive that explicitly creates a thunk, but I don't see why one can't, since primitives can create heap objects, and a thunk is just another heap object.

Comment: @raviqqe, one primop that can create a thunk is `tryTakeMVar# :: MVar# s a -> State# s -> (#State# s, Int#, a#)`. If the `MVar` is empty, it returns with an undefined value (a thunk that will produce an error if forced). The same goes for `tryReadMVar#`. It's not documented, but it looks like the same holds for `deRefWeak#` if someone tries to dereference a weak pointer whose key has been collected.